# Run SKLearnProcessor from AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have below code written in AWS Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook. But I would like to **run it from AWS Lambda (or AWS Step Functions)** to enable automated execution.

There is a *CreateProcessingJob* in Step Functions and [*sagemaker.processing.ProcessingJob*](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html?highlight=frameworkprocessor#sagemaker.processing.ProcessingJob)  in `sagemaker` API as well as [`create_processing_job`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_processing_job) in `boto3` - that's the closest I could find...

Is it possible to achieve? What would be the point of creating all of these Sagemaker functionalities if they have to be executed manually from the notebook..?

```
import boto3
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor
from sagemaker.processing import FrameworkProcessor
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingOutput

region = boto3.session.Session().region_name    
role = get_execution_role()

est_cls = sagemaker.sklearn.estimator.SKLearn
framework_version_str="0.23-1"

script_processor = FrameworkProcessor(
    role=role,
    instance_count=8,
    instance_type="ml.r5.8xlarge",
    volume_size_in_gb=120,
    max_runtime_in_seconds=432000,
    estimator_cls=est_cls,
    framework_version=framework_version_str
)

output_folder = 's3://bucket/out'

script_processor.run(
    code="preprocessing.py",
    source_dir = "code",
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(output_name='preprocessed_data', source="/opt/ml/processing/train"),
    ],
    arguments=["--bucket", "bucket", "--subfolder", "Training_data/"],
)

script_processor_job_description = script_processor.jobs[-1].describe()
print(script_processor_job_description)
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what's your end objective, so I'm listing both my answers

Option 1: Just to schedule run Sagemaker Notebooks
Below blog provides a way to do
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/a-guide-to-schedule-sagemaker-notebooks-a7a09eb641f6

Option 2 : Create and Orchestrate Sagemaker Pipelines
You need to create a workflow pipelines in sagemaker e.g. run once, later pipelines can be triggered using AWS Event Bridge.

https://github.com/aws-samples/scheduling-sagemaker-processing-with-sagemaker-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

It appears your code is written to trigger data preprocessing in Sagemaker, and this could be handled from Lambda via the [invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) method. Secondly, SageMaker provides a robust toolset for managing various aspects of the machine learning workflow, and a preprocessing activity like this is not limited to manual runs from within a Jupyter notebook. If your objective is automation, I would recommend checking out [SageMaker Pipelines](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pipelines/) to orchestrate and automate the workflows across each step of the machine learning process.

Comment: The Invoke method calls Lambda from Sagemaker - I need it the other way round. And for the automation I already have a big system set up in Step Functions. What I'd like to do is to connect Sagemaker to it, not to recreate everything in Pipelines. Also, there are some Sagemaker blocks in Step Functions, but none of them seem to fit here.

Comment: The invoke method is what triggers a Lambda invocation. That is what you would call if you need Lambda to initialize SageMaker.